# Implement Theano operation in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, theano

Following this [paper on domain adaptation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.07818.pdf), I am trying to implement the following layer for gradient reversal (written for Keras with the Theano backend, as found in this [Keras issue](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/3119)) in Tensorflow, as my model does not run well with Theano.

```
class GradientReversalLayer(Layer):
    """ Reverse a gradient
    <feedforward> return input x
    <backward> return -lambda * delta
    """
    def __init__(self, hp_lambda, **kwargs):
        super(GradientReversalLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hp_lambda = hp_lambda
        self.gr_op = ReverseGradient(self.hp_lambda)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.trainable_weights = []

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        return self.gr_op(x)

    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def get_config(self):
        config = {"name": self.__class__.__name__,
                         "lambda": self.hp_lambda}
        base_config = super(GradientReversalLayer, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

The layer performs this operation:

```
 import theano
    from keras.engine import Layer

    class ReverseGradient(theano.Op):
        """ theano operation to reverse the gradients
        Introduced in http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7495.pdf
        """

        view_map = {0: [0]}

        __props__ = ('hp_lambda', )

        def __init__(self, hp_lambda):
            super(ReverseGradient, self).__init__()
            self.hp_lambda = hp_lambda

        def make_node(self, x):
            assert hasattr(self, '_props'), "Your version of theano is too old to support __props__."
            x = theano.tensor.as_tensor_variable(x)
            return theano.Apply(self, [x], [x.type()])

        def perform(self, node, inputs, output_storage):
            xin, = inputs
            xout, = output_storage
            xout[0] = xin

        def grad(self, input, output_gradients):
            return [-self.hp_lambda * output_gradients[0]]

        def infer_shape(self, node, i0_shapes):
            return i0_shapes
```

## **Why can I not use it like this?**

If I run my model with the tf backend and with this function written in Theano I get the following error:

```
theano.tensor.var.AsTensorError: ('Cannot convert Tensor("concatenate_1/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 128), dtype=float32) to TensorType', <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>)
```

After calling it like this:

```
lstm_concat = concatenate([hidden_out_1, hidden_out_2])
lstm_concat = FlipGradientKeras.GradientReversalLayer(0.31)(lstm_concat)
```

## **How do I convert this operation to a TF [operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation)?**

The documentation about [adding a new operation](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op) only suggests to implement it in C++.

The [ops codes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/python/ops) show the general framework, but I'd like to be sure that everything that I'm implementing everything that the Theano op does.

I would assume it would be something on the lines of:

```
def ReverseGradient(input_tensor, hp_lambda):

    with ops.name_scope(name, "ReverseGradient", [input_tensor, hp_lambda]) as name:
        input_tensor = ops.convert_to_tensor(input_tensor, name="input_tensor")
```

But I'm really not sure about the rest.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by expanding on the work done [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/pull/4031).

Here's the working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.engine import Layer
import keras.backend as K

def reverse_gradient(X, hp_lambda):
    '''Flips the sign of the incoming gradient during training.'''
    try:
        reverse_gradient.num_calls += 1
    except AttributeError:
        reverse_gradient.num_calls = 1

    grad_name = "GradientReversal%d" % reverse_gradient.num_calls

    @tf.RegisterGradient(grad_name)
    def _flip_gradients(op, grad):
        return [tf.negative(grad) * hp_lambda]

    g = K.get_session().graph
    with g.gradient_override_map({'Identity': grad_name}):
        y = tf.identity(X)

    return y

class GradientReversal(Layer):
    '''Flip the sign of gradient during training.'''
    def __init__(self, hp_lambda, **kwargs):
        super(GradientReversal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.supports_masking = False
        self.hp_lambda = hp_lambda

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.trainable_weights = []

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        return reverse_gradient(x, self.hp_lambda)

    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape

    def get_config(self):
        config = {}
        base_config = super(GradientReversal, self).get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```